# Linear Algebra -Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Are the following subsets of $\Bbb R ^n$ subspaces? Justify the answer.

a) The set of all vectors $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ for which $x_1x_2x_3...x_n = 0$.

For this one I worked it out and got that it is not a subspace for $\Bbb R ^n$ since it is not closed under vector addition.

b) The set of all vectors $x \in \Bbb R ^n$ for which the sum of the even entries $(x_2, x_4, x_6, \dots)$ is zero and the sum of the odd entries $(x_1, x_3, x_5,\dots)$ is zero.

c) The set of all vectors $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ for which $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = 1$.

For this one I got that it is not a subspace because it is not closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication.

I was just wondering if I was correct for a) and c), however I am unsure about b).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: why is $a$ not a subspace ?? can you argue more !

Comment: You are right on a) and c), for the right reason. You seem to know enough to check the closure conditions for b). For future reference, take a look at how @alkabary 's edit made the mathematics look nice, and do it that way when you ask more questions.

Comment: (b) is a subspace  $(b)$ is a subspace , first it is closed under scalar multiplication

if $x_1 + x_3 = 0$ then $c(x_1 + x_3) = c \times 0 = 0$

and it is also closed under addition,

$x_2 + x_4 \in S$